# Minimax algorithm with weird behaviour when depth is high

Tags: c, minimax

I am writing a connect 4 ai using minimax and alpha-beta pruning. When I set the depth to something low like 10, it works as expected. When I set it to something higher like 20, the minimax algorithm takes too long time as expected because there is too many nodes to search. But when I set the depth to something high like 40, it finds a move really fast, and the move is often really bad. The number of nodes visited also stays the same with different high depths like 40 and 50. What could be the reason for this? Also, sometimes, the AI plays worse at higher depths than at lower depths. What could be the reason for this? The minimax function takes the depth into account when returning the evaluation, so it should favor the longest path to a loss/bad score and it should take the shortest path to win/good score.

Most relevant part of the code:

```
#define COLS 7
#define ROWS 6
#define SIZE COLS * ROWS

static int explore_order[COLS] = {3, 2, 4, 1, 5, 0, 6};
uint64_t bitboard[2];
int moves[SIZE];
int move_count = 0;
int initial_depth = 10;
int move_scores[COLS];
```

```
int c4_minimax(bool is_maximizing, int depth, int alpha, int beta) {
    if(c4_check_win(bitboard[(move_count) & 1])) {
        if(is_maximizing) {
            return MAX_SCORE; 
        }
        else {
            return MIN_SCORE;
        }
    }
    else if(c4_is_board_full()) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(depth == 0) {
        //return c4_evaluate();
        return 0;
    }

    bool* valid_moves = c4_get_valid_moves();
    if(is_maximizing == true) {
        int max_eval = MIN_SCORE;
        for(int i = 0;i < COLS;i++) {
            if(valid_moves[explore_order[i]] == true) {
                c4_make_move(explore_order[i]);
                int eval = c4_minimax(false, depth - 1, alpha, beta);
                c4_undo_move();
                max_eval = max(max_eval, eval);
                alpha = max(alpha, eval);
                if(beta <= alpha) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return max_eval - depth;
    }

    else {
        int min_eval = MAX_SCORE;
        for(int i = 0;i < COLS;i++) {
            if(valid_moves[explore_order[i]] == true) {
                c4_make_move(explore_order[i]);
                int eval = c4_minimax(true, depth - 1, alpha, beta);
                c4_undo_move();
                min_eval = min(min_eval, eval);
                beta = min(beta, eval);
                if(beta <= alpha) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return min_eval + depth;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Initial call:

```
int c4_find_best_move() {
    bool* valid_moves;
    int best_val = MIN_SCORE * 2;
    int move_val = 0;
    int column = -1;
    valid_moves = c4_get_valid_moves();
    for(int i = 0;i < COLS;i++) {
        if(valid_moves[explore_order[i]] == true) {
            c4_make_move(explore_order[i]);
            move_val = c4_minimax(false, initial_depth, MIN_SCORE, MAX_SCORE);
            move_scores[explore_order[i]] = move_val;
            c4_undo_move();
            if(move_val > best_val) {
                column = explore_order[i];
                best_val = move_val;
            }
        }
        else {
            //Non-valid moves:
            move_scores[explore_order[i]] = 0;
        }
    }
    return column;
}
```

```
bool* c4_get_valid_moves() {
    static bool valid_moves[COLS];
    for(int i = 0;i < COLS;i++) {
        if((TOP & ((uint64_t)1 << heights[i])) == 0) {
            valid_moves[i] = true;
        }
        else {
            valid_moves[i] = false;
        }
    }
    return valid_moves;
}
```

Comment: Please update your question to be a [mre] instead of a snippet of code.

Comment: Note: `else if(is_maximizing == false)` should be `else`

Comment: Generally, the behavior you describe indicates undefined behavior. An example of undefined behavior is accessing an array out of bounds. An access like `valid_moves[explore_order[i]]` is suspect. Is `explore_order[i]` actually a valid index for the `valid_moves` array at that point in the code?

Comment: There are a couple of tools you can use to detect out-of-bounds array access. With gcc or clang, compile with the `-fsanitize=address` option. Or use [valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/valgrind/info). You can also add `assert` statements to the code to check the index before using it.